# Faster collections.Counter - like operation for pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Hi I currently do the following to find all unique items in several pandas Series:

```
In [44]: data = [Series([1,2,7,4]), Series([2,5,3,1]), Series([3, 2, 4])]
In [45]: counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(data))
In [46]: unique_occurrences = [item for item, count in counts.items() if count == 1]
In [47]: unique_occurrences
Out[47]: [7, 5]
```

Is there any way to speed this up as  the real data is large.

Thanks.

**Feedback on answers**

Code:

```
def uniq_0(data):       # Original
    counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(data))
    return [item for item, count in counts.items() if count == 1]

def uniq_1(data):       # Divakar #1
    a = np.concatenate(data)
    unq,c = np.unique(a, return_counts=1)
    return unq[c==1]

def uniq_2(data):       # Divakar #2
    a = np.concatenate(data)
    return np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(a)==1)

def uniq_3(data):       # Divakar #3
    counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(data))
    k = np.array(list(counts.keys()))
    v = np.array(list(counts.values()))
    return k[v==1]

def uniq_4(data):       # Divakar #4
    L = max([i.max() for i in data])+1
    return np.flatnonzero(np.sum([np.bincount(i,minlength=L) 
                                  for i in data],axis=0)==1)

def uniq_5(data):       # Divakar #5
    L = max([i.max() for i in data])+1
    sums = np.zeros(L,dtype=int)
    for i in data:
        sums += np.bincount(i,minlength=L)
    return np.flatnonzero(sums==1)

def uniq_6(data):       # Erfan 
    v = pd.concat(data).value_counts()
    return v.index[v == 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [Series([1,2,7,4]), Series([2,5,3,1]), Series([3, 2, 4])]
    funcs = [uniq_0, uniq_1, uniq_2, uniq_3, uniq_4, uniq_5, uniq_6]
    answers = [f(data) for f in funcs]
    golden = set(answers[0])
    check = [set(a) == golden for a in answers]
    for n, a in enumerate(answers):
        if set(a) != golden:
            print(f'  Error with uniq_{n}(data)')
        else:
            print(f'  Confirmed uniq_{n}(data) == golden')
```

Spyder session:

```
  Confirmed uniq_0(data) == golden
  Confirmed uniq_1(data) == golden
  Confirmed uniq_2(data) == golden
  Confirmed uniq_3(data) == golden
  Confirmed uniq_4(data) == golden
  Confirmed uniq_5(data) == golden
  Confirmed uniq_6(data) == golden

In [73]: # 1000 Series. Averaging 10000.0 ints/Series. 405 ints unique.

In [74]: for f in funcs:
    ...:     print(f.__name__, end=': ')
    ...:     %timeit -r 3 f(data2)
uniq_0: 2.21 s ± 18.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
uniq_1: 465 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
uniq_2: 126 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
uniq_3: 2.22 s ± 48.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
uniq_4: 1.12 s ± 10.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
uniq_5: 374 ms ± 1.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
uniq_6: 831 ms ± 20.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)

In [75]:
```

Comment

A big thanks to you. My actual data is larger but won't fit on this laptop, but I feel I now have enough choices to really nail this. **Thanks again**!

Comment: Would it always have positive integers in the series?

Comment: It would always be +ve ints. I'll time some of those answers below  and give feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one NumPy array based one -

```
a = np.concatenate(data)
unq,c = np.unique(a, return_counts=1)
out = unq[c==1]
```

**Approach #2 (For positive integers data)**

For positive integers data, we can use `np.bincount` to get `out` directly from `a` -

```
out = np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(a)==1) # a from app#1
```

**Approach #3**

If we want to use `counts`, which we might prefer when working with a very large number of series, as concatenation could be slower in that scenario -

```
k = np.array(list(counts.keys()))
v = np.array(list(counts.values()))
out = k[v==1]
```

**Approach #4 (For positive integers data)**

With a large number of series holding positive integers, we can use `bincount` on each and thus avoid concatenation -

```
L = max([i.max() for i in data])+1
out = np.flatnonzero(np.sum([np.bincount(i,minlength=L) for i in data],axis=0)==1)
```

**Approach #5 (For positive integers data)**

This could be further improved on memory-efficiency, like so -

```
L = max([i.max() for i in data])+1
sums = np.zeros(L,dtype=int)
for i in data:
    sums += np.bincount(i,minlength=L)
out = np.flatnonzero(sums==1)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pd.concat` in combination with `value_counts` and apply Boolean indexing:

```
v = pd.concat(data).value_counts()
v.index[v == 1].to_numpy()
```

---

Which yields

```
array([7, 5], dtype=int64)
```

**Note**
If your pandas version is < 0.24.0 use instead:

```
v.index[v == 1].values
```

Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html).